# Where can I learn about MySQL master/slave, master/master, or clustering setups?

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, recovery, mysql-cluster

What are the best resources you've read or watched about setting up master/slave or clustering for database replication?

I don't know much about this. I have a database that is getting rather large and would like to make sure that if something goes wrong, I at least have some basic database infrastructure going on so I can recover data.

I'm using MySQL. I'm guessing that I do just as many reads as writes.

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me for sounding somewhat biased, but you can learn about setting up Master/Slave and Master/Master Replication right here in the DBA StackExchange.

Here are some of my posts

- `May 26, 2012` : [Trying to understand SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/trying-to-understand-show-slave-status-g/18438#18438)
- `Jan 05, 2012` : [MySQL Replication Error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/mysql-replication-error/10209#10209)
- `Dec 23, 2011` : [How to make MySQL replication reliable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/how-to-make-mysql-replication-reliable/9674#9674)
- `Dec 19, 2011` : [Best way to setup master to multi master replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/best-way-to-setup-master-to-multi-master-replication/9425#9425)
- `Feb 23, 2011` : [MySQL Replication - Introduce new Slave to replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/798/mysql-replication-introduce-new-slave-to-replication/1409#1409)

I also have posts concerning

- [MySQL and DRBD Clustering](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:877%20DRBD)
- [Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:877%20%5Bxtradb-cluster%5D)

[**Click here to see all MySQL Replication posts in the DBA StackExchange (not just mine)**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql+replication)

There is only one thing I cannot give advice on : [MySQL Cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/ndbcluster/topusers)

While I have answered some questions, there are three MySQL Cluster Experts here

- [Frazer Clement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4981/frazer-clement)
- [Mat Keep](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4224/mat-keep)
- [Andrew Morgan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4223/andrew-morgan)

Feel free to post your MySQL Replication questions or simply search through the already posted questions. You may find that what you are looking for is already answered.

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I work with the MySQL replication and MySQL Cluster teams

The best resources to get started for Replication are the Intro and Tutorial whitepapers posted here:
http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/#en-0-38

For MySQL Cluster, the evaluation guide provides insight into Cluster use cases and best practices for building a PoC:
http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-cluster-evaluation-guide/

Answer (score 1):

A great place to start is an Internet search, using your browser.

For instance, https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+clustering turns up a huge amount of relative and timely pages for your perusal.

For starters, I would read https://www.mysql.com/cluster which is literally the book on clustering.

Here's another great one:  http://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian